# PHP Round up long float to two decimals in accounting

Tags: php, decimal, rounding, precision, accounting

Say you have this number `562.9444445` and you want to round it up to 2 decimals. Now I would say that the result would be `562.95` as the 5 is carried up from the tail. No?

Well, the [PHP round function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) does not work like that. It will just check the next digit, in this case, the 3rd and return `562.94`.

I've tried with all the constant values of the `$mode` argument but none of them return the correct result.

I'm curious to know if anyone has encountered this and if there is a more precise rounding function that could be used.

I've found [this comment that can be useful](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#120232) but I think/hope something else might exist.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/881d518b6901fceb3b9c2556057bddec3e7e5d3b)

```
<?php
$value = 562.9445;

echo round($value,1)."\n"; // return 562.9 (correctly)
echo round($value,2)."\n"; // return 562.94 (wrong)
echo round($value,3)."\n"; // return 562.945 (correctly)
```

Comment: No. 562.94 is correct.

Comment: 1. That's not how rounding works. 2. This exact reason is why you should never use floats for currency.

Comment: If you round from the right-most edge, you will be rounding an already rounded number. Imagine you rounded from the let-most edge when rounding up and what would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function

```
<?php
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { 
    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
    return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 
} 
$value = 562.9445;

echo round_up ($value,1)."\n"; // return 563  
echo round_up ($value,2)."\n"; // return 562.95 
echo round_up ($value,3)."\n"; // return 562.945
```

if you need to use round function there is some options that dont siuts to you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$value = 562.9445;
echo(round($value,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,3,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "<br>");
echo ("<hr>");

echo(round($value ,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,3,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "<br>");
echo ("<hr>");
echo(round($value ,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,3,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
echo ("<hr>");
echo(round($value ,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) . "<br>");
echo(round($value ,3,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD));
?>

</body>
</html>
```

output:

```
562.9
562.94
562.945
562.9
562.94
562.944
562.9
562.94
562.944
562.9
562.94
562.945
```